# HTML code inside Python function doesn't work

Tags: python, html, email, formatting

I've written few lines of code for sending emails with the smtplib module.
If I run the script as it is:

```
import smtplib

message = """From: Sender <sender@randomemail.com>
To: Receiver <receive@randomemail.com>
Content-type: text/html
Subject: It works!
<b>It works!</b>\n
<br/>
<br/>
Do not reply to this email or god will strike you down.
"""

server = smtplib.SMTP('mysmtpserver')
sender = 'sender'
receiver = 'receive'

server.set_debuglevel(True)

server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

It executes just as intended. And I do have HTML formatting in the email received.

However, if I put the code as a function inside 'bigger' file along other functions:

```
def emailer():
    import smtplib

    message = """From: Sender <sender@randomemail.com>
    To: Receiver <receive@randomemail.com>
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: It works!
    <b>It works!</b>\n
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Do not reply to this email or god will strike you down.
    """

    server = smtplib.SMTP('mysmtpserver')
    sender = 'sender'
    receiver = 'receive'

    server.set_debuglevel(True)

    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

Then call the function:

```
emailer()
```

I get email with no HTML formatting and totally messed up subject and body, which then get's filtered as spam by my email provider.

I do need some explanation on how to fix that, and also advice if I can improve somehow what I've created.

Thanks

Comment: Your second version has a load of extra whitespace inside the `message` string (the spaces at the start of each line). Maybe you want to fix that.

Comment: (a) you should not do an `import` inside a function. They should always be at the top of your script. (b) It sounds like something elsewhere in your code is interfering with this but it's hard to say as you haven't provided any. I would suggest you take your working code, put it in a function with no other code and see if that works. Then you'll have eliminated the fact that it is in a function from being the culprit and can search for other areas of your code that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version has a load of extra whitespace inside the message string (the spaces at the start of each line).

First version:

```
From: Sender <sender@randomemail.com>
To: Receiver <receive@randomemail.com>
Content-type: text/html
Subject: It works!
<b>It works!</b>\n
<br/>
<br/>
Do not reply to this email or god will strike you down.
```

Second version:

```
From: Sender <sender@randomemail.com>
    To: Receiver <receive@randomemail.com>
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: It works!
    <b>It works!</b>\n
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Do not reply to this email or god will strike you down.
```

If there's any difference between the content of the two emails, it's probably that.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I've messed up the multi-line string as I've barely used that.
I've removed all the whitespace and my HTML formatting is working now.